# Find the coordinate matrix of a polynomial with respect to a non-standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I'm stuck on this question here:

Find the coordinate matrix of $2-4x-3x^2$ with respect to $B = {2, x^2-1, 1-2x-x^2}$

I did the following:

$a(2) + b(x^2 - 1) + c(1-2x-x^2) = 2-4x-3x^2$

But now I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You have only to complete your calculus:
$$
2a-b+c -2cx+(b-c)x^2=2-4x-3x^2
$$
So you find:
$$
\begin {cases}
2a-b+c=2\\
-2c=-4\\
b-c=-3
\end{cases}
$$
can you solve ?